# How to complete salesforce trail mix Task and links? I have complete all badges in trail mix. still it is showing incomplete

Tags: community, trailhead

I have Completed all the badges in trail mix salesforce. still it is showing incomplete because of task and links. How should i complete this?[image: il]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 'Follow' button on top right of that trailmix. You have to follow that trailmix then after that there will be button 'Mark as complete ' on  tasks and links.

So you can do that to complete it to 100% .

Comment: Please don't ask for upvotes on Stack Exchange; it's off topic

Answer (score 0):

I see that it's 87℅ complete so in essence you have to also complete the other link tasks and Mark them complete in addition to badge and also have to follow the trailmix as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with a Business Analyst career trailmix. The trails within the trailmix showed as "complete" but the trailmix still showed as 92% complete. I clicked the Unfollow button for the trailmix, then clicked the Follow button. This resolved the issue for me and the trailmix updated to Complete.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to combine Rebecca's and Mitesh's responses by first clicking "Unfollow" then "Follow" plus going back and "Mark as Complete" all of the reading again.